# Replace nodes with radials

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

This is my first exposure to d3.js. I'd like to replace the nodes in the tree with the radial graphs. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayazmemon/z1ocaow4/2/).

I believe this portion

```
// Declare the nodes…
   var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
   .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });
```

needs to be replaced with this.

```
var rp1 = radialProgress(document.getElementById('div1'))
            .label("RADIAL 1")
            .onClick(onClick1)
            .diameter(150)
            .value(78)
            .render();
```

When I replaced the declare node portion with the radial code nothing shows.

Comment: can you post the whole code on a fiddle...looking at this cannot understand what is _radialProgress_

Comment: the whole code is posted in the fiddle .. radialProgress begins at line 147 in the js window